# How to calculate the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \arctan \frac{1}{2^n}$?

Tags: calculus

I encountered the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \arctan \frac{1}{2^n}.$$
Use inequality $$\arctan x < x \ (x>0),$$ we know it converges.
but if I need to calculate its limit explicitly, how do I do that? Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: @dugu Do you have a reason that there is a closed-form expression for this sum?

Comment: The tangent of the first few terms is $1,3,13,-23,-335/37$

Comment: If you use the hint, you have a simple upper bound.

Comment: Each partial sum is the arctangent of a rational number. The sequence doesn't have an immediately obvious closed form, though.

Comment: Note that:
$$\arctan(x)+\arctan(y) = \arctan\left(\frac{x+y}{1-xy}\right)$$
So for example,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{2}\arctan(\frac{1}{2^n})=\arctan(\frac{6}{7}),\sum_{n=1}^{3}\arctan(\frac{1}{2^n})=\arctan(\frac{11}{10})$$ 
We construct a recursion:
$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}{1-\frac{a_n}{2^{n+1}}}, a_1=\frac{1}{2}$$
Then 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\arctan(\frac{1}{2^n})=\arctan(a_N)$$
So we need only find the limit of $a_n$.
I calculated this computationally and got the correct answer but couldn't solve it analytically, maybe someone else in the comments can.

Comment: Update: the limit of $a_N$ seems to be $1.421957261...$. Upon checking this against some databases I couldn't find a closed form expression. As people have pointed out, a closed form expression might not exist, did your question say that it does?

Comment: With Mathematica I have:$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\right)=\frac{1}{2} i \ln \left(\frac{i \left(i;\frac{1}{2}\right)_{\infty }}{\left(-i;\frac{1}{2}\right)_{\infty }}\right)$$ where: $\left(i;\frac{1}{2}\right)_{\infty }$ is gives the q-Pochhammer symbol.MMA code: `Sum[ArcTan[1/2^n], {n, 1, Infinity}] == 
 1/2 I Log[(I QPochhammer[I, 1/2])/QPochhammer[-I, 1/2]]`

Comment: The q-pochhammer symbol implies a connection with the jacobi theta functions. You could write the arctangent as a logarithm and turn the constant into a product

Comment: @TymaGaidash With `ln` expression is **simpler**. In this case **no** connection with the jacobi theta function.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use Taylor series to have bounds such as
$$x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}< \tan^{-1}(x) <x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}$$

Replace $x$ by $\frac 1{2^n}$ and make the summations from $x=1$ up to $\infty$. You should obtain tight bounds.